# singularity of an irreducible surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is it true that the singular locus of an irreducible hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ have pure co-dimension ?

Comment: The singular locus of the quartic surface $XY(X-T)^2+Z^4=0$  is the union of the line $X=T$, $Z=0$ and the point $X=Y=Z=0$.

Comment: However, the non-normal locus of a hypersurface has pure codimension 1.  (You really just need S2 for this).